# Drupal 7 ajax from ahah

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drupal-7

i have this form:

```
function tax_assistant_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    //questa funzione è usata per alterare la disposizione del form originale
    //contenuto in un altro modulo (linkableobject)
    if ($form_id == 'linkableobject_node_form') {
    $vid=26;
            $query=taxonomy_get_tree($vid);
        //Creo funzione per array name vocabulary
        foreach($query as $rec){
        $form["prova"]= array(
        '#type'=> 'select',
        '#title'=> t($rec->name),
        '#options'=>array(get_vid($vid)),
        '#ajax' => array(
                    'callback'=>'get_synonyms',
                'wrapper'=>'area_sinonimi',
                'replace'=>'TRUE',
                    ),
        );
    }
        //form dei sinonimi        
        $form['sinonimi'] = array(
          // '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#title'=> t('Sinonimi'),
            '#prefix' => '<div id="area_sinonimi">Qui andrebbero i sinonimi',
            '#suffix' => '</div>',
        );
 }
```

and recall with ajax this function get_synonyms

```
function get_synonyms() {
    $form_build_id = $_POST['form_build_id'];
    $form_state = array('submitted' => FALSE);
    $form = form_get_cache($form_build_id, $form_state);
    $output="";
    $synonyms = '';
    $vid=26;
        $tid = $_POST['prova'];
        $result = db_query('SELECT name FROM {taxonomy_term_synonym} where tid=:tid', array(':tid'=>$tid));
    //print_r($result);
        $voc = get_vocabolario($vid);
        if ($tid > 0)
            $synonyms .= "<b>Synonyms for $voc:</b></br>";
        foreach ($result as $rec) {
            $synonyms.= "<i>'" . $rec->name . "';</i> ";
            $keywords[$rec->name] = $rec->name;
        }

        $form['sinonimi'] = array(
            '#type' => 'item',
            '#description' => t("In order to facilitate the cataloging of your learning object,
      try to make use of these terms for its description"),
            '#value' => $synonyms,
        );
        $synonyms.='</br>';


    form_set_cache($_POST['form_id'], $form, $form_state);

    $form = form_builder($_POST['form_id'], $form, $form_state);

    $output.=drupal_render($form['sinonimi']);


    drupal_json_encode(array('status' => TRUE, 'data' => $output));

    exit;
}
```

but give me this error `Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to drupal_array_set_nested_value() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/html/glorep/includes/form.inc on line 2532 and defined in drupal_array_set_nested_value() (line 6598 of /var/www/html/glorep/includes/common.inc)`.
I think the probles is ajax, i have upgrade this from D6 when there is D6, but i can understand how modify, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

1. Please read this https://drupal.org/coding-standards and update your code.
2. You're adding form element ($form["prova"]) with the same name in loop. So each iteration will replace existing element with new one.
3. Check value of $tid = $_POST['prova']; because it depends from which options was set for this select box. I expect that you didn't set the keys for options.
4. Check arguments of drupal_array_set_nested_value() function.
5. Install and configure xdebug and will be able to find a bug in 1 minute.

Comment: Thanks for help! =)
OK, now i read that!
The varibale $tid is full, i stamp it with drupal_set_message and the $form['sinonimi'] is full too!
This form is based on another form, i think the problem is in the second form because drupal_Set_netsted_value() is call on drupal_validate_form!

Comment: @Dewitt , Just a suggestion: you can damp any variable using var_dump($var);, watchdog('dump', print_r($var, 1)); or dpm($var) if you have devel module installed. But better way is to use xdebug to check exact value at running time.

Comment: thanks, i try it and the result it's the same, the problem is the form!